# Cached Fetch for User Roles from NHibernate in an MVC App

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping, syscache2, nhibernate-profiler

Using classes like this...

```
public class Login
{
    public virtual Guid LoginId { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Email { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Group> Groups { get; set; }
}

public class Group
{
    public virtual Guid GroupId { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Login> Logins { get; set; }
}

public class Role : ITerminable
{
    public virtual Guid RoleId { get; set; }
    public virtual string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public virtual string RoleName { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
}
```

And an ERD that looks like this...
[image: Data Model ERD]

This is my current query.

```
var login = loginRepository.Query().Where(x => x.Name == username).FetchMany(x=>x.Groups).ThenFetchMany(x=>x.Roles).SingleOrDefault();
return login.Groups.SelectMany(x => x.Roles).Distinct().ToList();
```

The problem is that while the first request to my site is always fine and goes through as a single query for the current user's Roles, subsequent ones result in NHibernate Profiler showing lots of cached queries (one for every role). I'm not entirely sure if this is a red flag or not (I'm using SysCache2, but it's not using Database Dependencies at the moment). But I would like to try and find a way to clear itup.

Is there a way to fix this so that I don't get a cache hit for every single role on every request when the first request was just one database hit? Or as an analogy, am I misinterpreting condensation on a pipe as a leak?

Comment: A cache hit is usually a good thing...

Comment: Absolutely, I guess I'm wondering if I should be concerned that it's showing the cache hit entries for every role individually in the profiler rather than showing one cache hit entry for the cached query as a whole? That and I'm kind of getting tired of having to scroll through 150+ cache hits in the profiler every time I want to see what the rest of the entries are.

Comment: No, you shouldn't worry. Entity cache is separate from query cache, which caches ids only.

Comment: Ok. That's good enough for me. Thanks taking the time to explain this. If you could put a quick answer on this question I'll accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entity cache is separate from the query cache.

The query cache only stores the ids resulting from the query execution, so retrieving the entities back involves getting that list, and then getting all the values from the entity cache.